# How to allow Flask for very long operations?

Tags: python, html, http, flask

I've wrote flask app which in some cases is executing time consuming operations which are relatively long (2-5min). While executing code on localhost it is working fine, but while doing the same on Azure host, after approximately 45 seconds it returns internal server error. How to handle this? How to allow flask for such time consuming operations?

Comment: It would be helpful to state what type of operation your app does.
However, without more information recommended solution is Celery (or another task queue tool).

Comment: Generally you want CPU intensive operations to run **asynchronously** from your flask app. For example, when a user registers on your website, the website should continue functioning _while_ the initial registration e-mail is being prepared and sent to user. It should not freeze up.

This is done by running the task in another instance of python separate from your Flask app. As @janmperterka mention, Celery is one tool that can help with that.